# Unable to click in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to crawl the HTML data.

And, I tried headless browser in CasperJS.

But, Can't able to click.

*- The following is tried code in CapserJS.*

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var mouse = require('mouse').create(casper);

casper.start('http://sts.kma.go.kr/jsp/home/contents/climateData/smart/smartStatisticsSearch.do', function() {
    this.echo('START');
    });

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture("1.png");

    this.mouse.click('li[class="item1"]');

    casper.wait(5000, function() {      
      this.capture("2.png");
      });
    });

casper.run(function() {
    this.capture('3.png');
    this.echo('EXIT');
    casper.exit();
    });
```

In code, "1.png" is capture file ago click event. "2.png" is capture file after click event. "3.png" is capture file after click event and after "run" method.

But, "1.png", "2.png", "3.png" are equal result.

Help me.

Comment: I solved this problem through jQuery.

Comment: this.mouse.click('li[class="item1"]'); -> $('li[class="item1"] a').click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your selector to `this.mouse.click('li[class="item1"] > a')` because the `li[class="item1"]` is not clickable, but the `a` element inside of it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using this instead, and see if it works (it works for me):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = 'http://sts.kma.go.kr/jsp/home/contents/climateData/smart/smartStatisticsSearch.do';

casper.start(url).then(function() 
    {
        this.echo('START');
        this.capture('1.png');
    }).thenClick('li[class="item1"] > a').then(function() 
    {
        this.capture('2.png');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.capture('3.png');
    this.echo('EXIT').exit();
});
```